# Safely write part of a file algorithm (atomic part write)

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql, disk, acid

assume I want to write simple database (work on linux), which must satisfy following conditions:

It has only two functions:

1. write_chunk(index, bytes)
2. read_chunk(index)

Where index is integer from 0 to 1M, and bytes is chunk of 100 bytes.
I want file states transfer atomically after each call of write_chunk.

So I want be sure:

1. Block of 100 bytes writes in file at position index*100
2. All 100 bytes written atomic (or not writes at all)
3. If suddenly power off happens at write (previous valid 100 bytes
   restored)

I imagine implementations like this:

**Write function implementation:**

1. Before we start write 100 bytes we copy previous 100 bytes  from
   position index*100 to another file for rollback (index also copied).
   also we sign all rollback file data with hash. Do fsync on rollback.
2. Then we start write new 100 bytes at position index*100, do
   fsync.
3. If step 2 is ok we delete all data from rollback file.
4. We return ok to function caller.

**Read function implementation:**

1. If we start to read and rollback file not empty and valid, we
   restore 100 bytes from rollback and delete rollback or just delete
   rollback if hash not valid.
2. We read chunk from position index*100 and return data

Is I safe with following algorithm?

**So I want be sure what I am on the same level of safety as databases like MySQL or PostgreSQL** execute insert statement after commit.

What techniques can I use to guaranty atomic and durable writes? I mean may be I need use some hashing on chunk also to ensure it valid or use double copy of rollback file. Or store data in rollback file a little bit in a time to ensure disk subsystems flush. (I heard what I not safe even if I call fsync after write it depends of the disk subsystem then it physically writes data).

Answer (score 0):

That should work as long as you have no concurrency, that is, only one of these functions is allowed to run at the same time.

Why don't you use a simple *embedded database*?

Comment: This more for study purposes, what if I implement something like actors model,  where i have millions of actors, where state of actor only visible for itself via one coroutine and no shared blocks of data.